# How to truncate text in cell in Bootstrap Table in React?

Tags: javascript, css, react-bootstrap, truncate, react-table

I have a Bootstrap Table component, and one cell within that table is a URL. The URL can be long, so I'd like to automatically truncate it with an ellipsis to fit within the cell.

[Here's an example of what the issue looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06CcZ.png)

You can see the URL and the Table exceed the width of the Card component they're in.

I managed to come up with a fix, but it's not ideal. Here's my code:

```html
<div>
  <Accordion>
    {this.state.previous_entries.map(pe =>
      <Card key={pe.listing.id}>
        <CustomToggle eventKey={pe.listing.id}>{[formatAddress(pe), pe.listing.createdAt]}</CustomToggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={pe.listing.id}>
          <Card.Body>
            <Table bordered style={{marginBottom: 0}}>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td className="bg-light">URL</td>
                  <td colSpan="3">
                    <!-- THIS PART -->
                    <a href={pe.listing.url}>
                      <span style={{textOverflow: "ellipsis", overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace:"nowrap", position: "fixed", maxWidth: "14%"}}>{ pe.listing.url }</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="bg-light">Monthly Rent</td>
                  <td>{ pe.listing.monthly_rent ? pe.listing.monthly_rent + "万円" : "N/A" }</td>
                  <td className="bg-light">礼金</td>
                  <td>{ pe.listing.reikin !== null ? (pe.listing.reikin !== 0 ? pe.listing.reikin + "ヶ月" : pe.listing.reikin) : "N/A" }</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="bg-light">敷金</td>
                  <td>{ pe.listing.security_deposit !== null ? (pe.listing.security_deposit !== 0 ? pe.listing.security_deposit + "ヶ月" : pe.listing.security_deposit) : "N/A" }</td>
                  <td className="bg-light">面積</td>
                  <td>{ pe.listing.square_m ? pe.listing.square_m + "m²" : "N/A" }</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="bg-light">Closest Station</td>
                  <td>{ pe.listing.closest_station ? pe.listing.closest_station : "N/A" }</td>
                  <td className="bg-light">Walking Time</td>
                  <td>{ pe.listing.walking_time ? pe.listing.walking_time + "分" : "N/A" }</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td className="bg-light">Availability</td>
                  <td>{ pe.listing.availability ? pe.listing.availability : "N/A" }</td>
                  <td className="bg-light">Interest</td>
                  <td>{ pe.property.interest ? pe.property.interest : "N/A" }</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </Table>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    )}
  </Accordion>
</div>
```

My 'fix' was adding the `maxWidth: "14%"` style to the span containing the URL. But this doesn't work great in all cases, depending on the size of the window. Which makes sense because it's a static value.

[Here's what my 'fix' looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOoIe.png)

Does someone know a better way of automatically truncating the URL so that the Table doesn't exceed the Card?

Comment: Try using `word-wrap: break-word`.

Comment: I don't want it to wrap. I want it to truncate. Regardless I tried your suggest and it didn't work. Thanks tho!

Comment: Have u tried text-overflow: ellipsis ?

Comment: Yeah, its in my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is more flexible when it comes to various screen sizes, as you are not specifying a width for the `text-overflow`.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td>a {
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

td>a>span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <Accordion>
    {this.state.previous_entries.map(pe =>
    <Card key={pe.listing.id}>
      <CustomToggle eventKey={pe.listing.id}>{[formatAddress(pe), pe.listing.createdAt]}</CustomToggle>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={pe.listing.id}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Table bordered style={{marginBottom: 0}}>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="bg-light">URL</td>
                <td colSpan="3">
                  <!-- THIS PART -->
                  <a href={pe.listing.url}>
                    <span style={{textOverflow: "ellipsis", overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace: "nowrap", position: "fixed", maxWidth: "14%"}}>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="bg-light">Monthly Rent</td>
                <td>{ pe.listing.monthly_rent ? pe.listing.monthly_rent + "万円" : "N/A" }</td>
                <td className="bg-light">礼金</td>
                <td>{ pe.listing.reikin !== null ? (pe.listing.reikin !== 0 ? pe.listing.reikin + "ヶ月" : pe.listing.reikin) : "N/A" }</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="bg-light">敷金</td>
                <td>{ pe.listing.security_deposit !== null ? (pe.listing.security_deposit !== 0 ? pe.listing.security_deposit + "ヶ月" : pe.listing.security_deposit) : "N/A" }</td>
                <td className="bg-light">面積</td>
                <td>{ pe.listing.square_m ? pe.listing.square_m + "m²" : "N/A" }</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="bg-light">Closest Station</td>
                <td>{ pe.listing.closest_station ? pe.listing.closest_station : "N/A" }</td>
                <td className="bg-light">Walking Time</td>
                <td>{ pe.listing.walking_time ? pe.listing.walking_time + "分" : "N/A" }</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td className="bg-light">Availability</td>
                <td>{ pe.listing.availability ? pe.listing.availability : "N/A" }</td>
                <td className="bg-light">Interest</td>
                <td>{ pe.property.interest ? pe.property.interest : "N/A" }</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Card.Body>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
    )}
  </Accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed everything! Thanks so much! I was stuck on this for hours.

Comment: No problem mate. :)